# Register same interface multiple times - Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm trying to register an interface with different config as below:

```
private static ContainerBuilder RegisterAzureStorage(this ContainerBuilder containerBuilder, IAzureStorageOptions azureStorageOptions)
    {
        containerBuilder.Register(c =>
                new AzureStorageKeyValuePersistenceService(
                    new AzureStorageKeyValuePersistenceConfig(
                        azureStorageOptions.DctAzureBlobConnectionString,
                        azureStorageOptions.DctAzureBlobContainerName)))
            .As<IStreamableKeyValuePersistenceService>()
            .Keyed<IStreamableKeyValuePersistenceService>(PersistenceStorageKeys.DctAzureStorage)
            .SingleInstance();

        containerBuilder.Register(c =>
                new AzureStorageKeyValuePersistenceService(
                    new AzureStorageKeyValuePersistenceConfig(
                        azureStorageOptions.NcsAzureBlobConnectionString,
                        azureStorageOptions.NcsAzureBlobContainerName)))
            .As<IStreamableKeyValuePersistenceService>()
            .Keyed<IStreamableKeyValuePersistenceService>(PersistenceStorageKeys.NcsAzureStorage)
            .SingleInstance();

        return containerBuilder;
    }
```

Then in my constuctor:

```
public ReportingController(
        [KeyFilter(PersistenceStorageKeys.DctAzureStorage)] IStreamableKeyValuePersistenceService dctStorage,
        [KeyFilter(PersistenceStorageKeys.NcsAzureStorage)] IStreamableKeyValuePersistenceService ncsStorage)
    {
        _dctStorage = dctStorage;
        _ncsStorage = ncsStorage;
    }
```

And the Usage:

```
await _dctStorage.SaveAsync(........);
await _ncsStorage.SaveAsync(........);
```

However, when executing it's only picking up the last registration and saving both objects to the same location.

I can get it to work using the enumerable method:

```
public ReportingController(IEnumerable<IStreamableKeyValuePersistenceService> storage)
    {
        _storage = storage;
    }
```

and then for eaching over the enumerable, but I would prefer to use the keyed method if possible.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this issue in the future I was missing a registration, the executing interface in this case `IReportingController` needs to be registered with the `WithAttributeFiltering()` as below:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<ReportingController>().As<IReportingController>().WithAttributeFiltering();
```